# How to make hasClass() check every second

Tags: javascript, jquery, class

I want to make a slider(5 imgs), I have 5 buttons under the images, and two direction buttons(prev and next)

When one of those 5 buttons is click, the class (flex-active) is activated for it.

When the 3th button (for example) has class (flex-active) and the button with class (flex-next) is clicked i want to activate a function  "img4" (that will show img4 and remove (flex-active) from 3th button and add to the 4th button).

By default, the first button has flex-active. It works this method only from 1 to 2 and 1 back to 5.

The problem is that hasClass checks only at the begining who has that class, but if i change it manually and then click next button, it will work img2 function, because the first button has (flex-active).

This work :

```
 if($("a.1").hasClass("flex-active") ){
     $(".flex-prev").click(img5);
 };     

 if($("a.1").hasClass("flex-active") ){
    $(".flex-next").click(img2);
 };
```

This not:

```
 if($("a.2").hasClass("flex-active") ){
    $(".flex-prev").click(img1);
 };
```

Comment: `setInterval(function(){/*code*/},1000/*milliseconds*/);`?

Comment: I really wouldn't use a `setInterval` for this, try to hook in to the event that is adding or removing the class. That should be much more effective and reliable.

Comment: are your buttons(all five) are next to each other in HTML code ?

Comment: No, there are 5 li and inside of a li is a button, but i can select them with jquery if it needs.

Answer (score 0):

what you might do is that you assign a specific class name for your images

```
<li><img class="slider flex-active" src=".../></li>
<li><img class="slider" src=".../></li>
...
```

and dynamically on pressing on the buttons you do `next()` or `previous` based on the direction you wish

```
$('button').on('click',function() {
   $('img.slider').hasClass('flex-active').removeClass('flex-active').next().addClass('flex-active');
});
```

Comment: thank you for the answer, but this code will only change the class of the 5 buttons, will not show the img1, img2...img5. I need something to know what button is active from those five.

Comment: then when you click on that button add a specific class to it, then you will know which button is active. It would be helpful if you post your whole code or have a Jsfiddle